# How make column nullable of scalar field in subclass (single table)?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hierarchy with single table mapping.
I use HSQLDB for testing purposes with auto generation DDL feature.
One of subclasses in the hierarchy has a scalar long field.

I cannot persist object of other subclass because a DB row field of the first class gets null.

Hibernate generates table column with not null constraint.

The problem disappears if change field type to Long.
But @Nullable annotation doesn't help.

I don't want to use Long type instead long because this lead
to often boxing/unboxing.

Comment: Why would you want such? There's no such thing as a null long (primitive), therefore if your table were to have one, your translation to an entity object would blow up.

Comment: I map different objects of different classes into one table.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it.

Just add @Column(nullable = true) on field in embeddable class.

```
@Embeddable
class Delay {
   @Colum(nullable = true)
   private long delay;

}
```